# Empty Weights not working Rigify

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

So I was making a rig and it was working just fine earlier when I regenerated the rig but when I did it again and applied the empty groups like I usually do it just completely broke.  I've already deleted all vertex groups and redid the rig but the problem is still there. Some weight paint is just not transferring when I regenerated the rig, and both automatic weights and envelop weights don't work since I have some manual weight paint. But the problem only happens when I regenerate the rig. The base rig still works fine

[image][image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "regenerating a rig". It will be useful to provide the steps you are performing that lead to the undesired result in more detail as this could help finding the solution quicker.

Comment: have you tried to check if there's another modifier in the object? seems like you parented 2 different armatures, also try to unparent all then try again

Comment: Hi Anity, sorry for the late response but I've already tried doing that and still no luck. For some reason the rig just has deformation off and I have to usually manually turn it on but that isn't the problem, the problem is that the weights from the reference rig don't transfer to the generated rig for whatever reason when it was working fine a while ago.